# Get Select2 Selected Value From Code Behind ASP .Net Web Form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I have a problem with Select2 V 4.02

Here is my code

```
<select id="MySelect" class="form-control" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
<asp:Button Text="Show Select2 Result" runat="server" ID="btnShow" OnClick="btnShow_Click"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#MySelect').select2({
        placeholder: "-Select-"
});
```

My question is:
Can I get the "MySelect" selected value from ASP .Net Code behind? 
I tried this code from code behind asp .net webform

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(MySelect.Value);
}
```

But it returns empty string.

Comment: It must have returned the first value, which is empty. Have you tried selecting A, B or C and checked in code-behind?

Comment: Yes, I have tried It. It still shows empty string as result. I have debugged it and add watch "MySelect", but there are no properties that shows the selected value

Comment: Which event is triggered in code-behind where you checked MySelect.Value?

Comment: I will edit my questiong to make it clear

Comment: Is that what you mean? @BikashSinghMaharjan

Comment: Okay. I just did a quick test in fresh Webform. It seems to be fine. I can get the selected value in button click event of code-behind. That's why i need to know more in order to solve this case. Check out http://imgur.com/XMa4k9J

Comment: Why are you using select and not DropDownList?

Comment: By the way I am using this library for Select2: https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use standard hidden field like this :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" runat="server" />
```

then in your JavaScript :

```
$('#MySelect').on('change', function () {
   $('#<%=hf1.ClientID%>').val($(this).val());
}
```

in your code behind :

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(hf1.Value);
}
```

i hope work for you